# Can I specify a closure which captures nothing?

Tags: rust

While closures are powerful, they can lead to bugs if used carelessly. An example is a closure that modifies its captured variables when this is not wanted. Sometimes we only need an anonymous function that has no free variables. That is, it captures nothing. Can I specify a closure as capturing nothing and get this checked by the compiler? Something like `none |...| {...}` looks ideal. I know I can define a function in current scope but it's not as elegant as a variable containing an anonymous function.

Comment: If you don't want a closure to be able to close over its surrounding scope, don't use a closure, use a nested function. You may not find it as elegant but that's why they exist alongside closures in the first place.

Comment: @isaactfa How do you write lambda with nested named functions? Wouldn't that be awkward?

Comment: @TSK We might need more context about your specific usecase, your question doesn't have a unique answer for the general case.

Comment: @Finomnis Specific use case for non-capturing closures? Implementing a calculator that operates on two numbers and you don't want irrelevant internal state of the calculator to be mutated while doing the calculation?

Comment: No I mean your code layout. *"How do you write a lambda with nested named functions"* - I think he meant use nested named functions **instead** of a closure.

Comment: @Finomnis Yes that's what he meant and I thought that'd be awkward if your code makes heavy use of anonymous functions because you'd have to name each and the function names pollute the scope.

Comment: @TSK Ok I got you.

Comment: "While closures are powerful, they can lead to bugs if used carelessly. An example is a closure that modifies its captured variables when this is not wanted." note that this issue is much more minor in Rust than in other languages because of borrowck & al, it's pretty difficult to have two closures conflicting on the update of a local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only non capturing closures can coerce to function pointers. You can use this fact to check that the closure is non-capturing by attempting to coerce it to a function pointer:

```rust
let closure = || {};
let _: fn() = closure;
```

You can wrap it in a macro to make this convenient:

```rust
macro_rules! enforce_non_capturing {
    // This macro does not allow specifying the return type (`|| -> Ret {}`),
    // but it can be adjusted to allow that.
    // It also does not allow patterns as parameter names, but allowing that
    // is harder.
    (
        | $( $param:ident $( : $param_ty:ty )? ),* $(,)? | $body:expr
    ) => {{
        let closure = | $( $param $( : $param_ty )?, )* | $body;
        // We want to generate `fn(_, _, ...) -> _` with underscores as the number of parameters.
        // We use a dummy repetition to achieve that.
        let _: fn( $( enforce_non_capturing!(@replace_with_underscore $param ), )* ) -> _ = closure;
        closure
    }};
    // `||` is recognized as one token instead of two, so we need another arm.
    ( || $body:expr ) => { enforce_non_capturing!(| | $body) };
    (@replace_with_underscore $param:ident) => { _ };
}

fn main() {
    // Compiles.
    let closure = enforce_non_capturing!(|| {});
    closure();
    let a = 0;
    // Doesn't compile.
    // let closure = enforce_non_capturing!(|| a);
    // closure();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=230838c67d269657cc19fe39ab5f6009).

Comment: I actually prefer this approach. It only requires adding a type to the closure variable. But what if the function argument types are not obvious?

Comment: @TSK Which approach? You can specify `_` to infer them (this is what the macro does).

Comment: The overall idea of coercing closure to function to ensure it's non-capturing.

Comment: Do you know anything that serves a "function" type for any functions so we can avoid this macro? The macro is basically filling in the correct number of `_` as argument types.

Comment: What's your usecase? You must be using those closures somewhere, how do they get called? I feel like you should restrict them where you use them, like @prog-fh suggests. Your questions strongly depend on the code layout you have, so please provide some code example.

Comment: @TSK This is not easy because of the coercion. I think I can build something using nightly Rust, but I don't think this is better than a macro.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the constraint could not be expressed where the closure/function is provided, but where it is expected.

In this example, `fnct2()` cannot receive a closure.

```rust
fn fnct1(mut f: impl FnMut(i32) -> i32) {
    println!("{}", f(10));
}

fn fnct2(f: fn(i32) -> i32) {
    println!("{}", f(20));
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    fnct1(|n| {
        x += 1;
        n + x
    });
    fnct2(|n| {
        // x += 2; // ERROR: expected fn pointer, found closure
        // n + x
        n + 2
    });
    println!("x={}", x);
}
/*
11
22
x=1
*/
```

Comment: While your code example is a little messy, I actually think that this answer gives the best advice. If the function expects a non-capturing closure, it should express so in its parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

While this is most certainly not a 'best practice', you can store the closure in a function pointer. Function pointers can only hold non-capturing closures.

This works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let c: fn() = || {
        println!("Hello world!");
    };

    c();
}
```

```
Hello world!
```

While this doesn't:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = 10;
    let c: fn() = || {
        a += 1;
    };
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:19
  |
3 |       let c: fn() = || {
  |  ____________----___^
  | |            |
  | |            expected due to this
4 | |         a += 1;
5 | |     };
  | |_____^ expected fn pointer, found closure
  |
  = note: expected fn pointer `fn()`
                found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:3:19: 3:21]`
note: closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |         a += 1;
  |         ^ `a` captured here
```

Comment: Note that while this works, this may be little less performant as the compiler may not be able to devirtualize the call (but most chances it will).

Comment: Note for other people who read this, @ChayimFriedman with *a little less* he really does mean *a little*. It makes very little difference. This is only relevant for high-performance applications.

Comment: Typing the closure variable with function pointer looks good. But is there a way to avoid specifying an exact function signature? When the closure has many bound variables the signature gets clumsy. Is there a super type for all function pointers?

Comment: @TSK no, because a function pointer is a primitive type. Please provide some code from your project to help you further, I feel like this is becoming very context dependent.

Comment: @TSK in that case your question about "having to specify the type manually" might be a misguided question, because you will have to specify it anyway when you pass it as a parameter into a function or similar. I'm sure that's the whole point of using a closure here and not just executing the code directly. And at this point you will need to specify the type. And @prog-fh suggests that at this point you specify a `fn` instead of an `impl Fn`/`impl FnMut`/`impl FnOnce`. Then you don't need to specify any type for your actual variable, because the error will appear later when you try to use it.